# How to add new Application consumers on the fly in Kafka

Tags: python, events, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, consumer

I am working on an event driven flow architecture and I'd like to have as many independent applications consuming from the same topic independently (not in the same consumer group). To do that I'd create one consumer group for each new application but I'd like to do that automatically through a system. Is that possible and is that the best approach?

By the way we are coding with Python.

Thanks.

Comment: A new group is how you do it, but what do you mean "automatically"? You will need to run the code yourself manually and alter the consumer group value when you do so

Comment: "automatically" like using some API instead of having a human running some Kafka command line to create a new consumer group.

Comment: But you don't use a CLI to create the groups anyways, you just start the app with the group defined

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change the value of the `group.id` property while creating the consumer. You can do this either manually in each application or you can generate a random string using the UUID generator in Python